# Bind checkbox value with controller boolean variable

Tags: apex, visualforce, inputcheckboxes, bind-variable

**I have checkboxes on my vf page**

`<apex:inputCheckbox id="checkboxShowP" value="{!P}" onchange="show(this);"/>`

**In the controller class**

```
public boolean P{get;set;}
```

I want to bind this checkbox value to a boolean variable. But when I display the `P` value of apex class it is showing up as `null`. Is it possible to bind variable values in this way?

Comment: Can you add your relevant VF code here?

Comment: i added the code. The tags are not being displayed for some reason

Comment: wrap the markup inside a "pre" tag. like <pre> YOUR HTML CODE </pre>

Comment: I removed the tag brackets from my code

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have not initialised the value for "P". Initialise the value in the constructor.

> **VF Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="CheckboxController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkboxShowP" value="{!P}" onchange="show(this);"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

> **Apex Class:**

```
public with sharing class CheckboxController {

    public Boolean P{ get; set; }

    public CheckboxController(){
        this.P = true;
    }
}
```

[image: Checkbox]

Do check the Apex and VF trailhead for an understanding of dynamic bindings.

Custom Controllers : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_custom.htm

Comment: I already tried this. However, the value of the boolean remains as what was initialized in the Constructor. It does not change according to the check/uncheck in VF page @Sumuga